# How to export custom search folders in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, export

In Outlook it is possible to export **the logic**, not the contents of custom search folders?

What I have tried:

- Right-clicking the search folders and looking in the available menus
- Looked in Outlook's Import/Export menu, but I'm only able to export real folders to `.pst` etc.
- Looked in the Rules menu

Answer (score -3):

Once you create your search folder, create a new subfolder within your inbox and copy the the contents (not the folder itself) to the new subfolder.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) needs to be expanded.  It's unclear how this is a solution to the OP's question. Please edit it to explain *how* your answer solves the OPs problem.